# Timer tick event continue or exit

Tags: .net, wpf

I wonder the problem, is when I call the Timer event:

```
DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
              {
               
                  MyCode();
                  Timer.Stop();
              };

Timer.Start();
Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

private static void MyCode() { /* EXAMPLE MY CODE RUN */ }
```

So will my MyCode run out of thread before Timer.Stop() or not?

Comment: "will function X run out of thread before event Y" -- this may mean something to you, but it does not mean anything to anyone who reads it.

Comment: No, DispatcherTimer raises its event on the dispatcher thread.

Comment: What is Timer.Close()? Where did you found it?

Comment: Sorry Timer.Close() I am confused with Close Form :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You start the timer before you set the interval, so the `Tick` event will be triggered immediately rather than after 10 sec.
- The DispatcherTimer does not have a `Close` method. You probably mean `Stop`?
- In the `Tick` event, you call `MyCode` before you stop the Timer. It is probably better to first stop the Timer, before you call `MyCode`.

So a suggestion for your code:

```
DispatcherTimer Timer = new { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
          {               
              Timer.Stop();
              MyCode();
          };
Timer.Start();
...

private static void MyCode() { /* EXAMPLE MY CODE RUN */ }
```